# The first unique integer value in a list in Python

Tags: python

I want find the first unique number in a list, but I have a error.
My code:

```
s=[1,2,1,2,3,5]
mydict={}
for i in s:
    if(i in mydict):
        mydict[i]=mydict[i]+1
    else:
        mydict=1

for key in mydict:
    if (mydict[key]==1):
        print(key)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abdul_saboor/PycharmProjects/sleneiumpythonsession/Selenium sessions/firstuniquenumber.py", line 4, in <module>
    if(i in mydict):
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: As soon as you do `mydict=1`, what you're calling `mydict` is no longer a dictionary.

Comment: Presumably you meant `mydict[i] = 1`

Comment: Code [x] , ErrorMessage [x], WhatIWantStatement [x] ... not sure why its downvoted that much - probably because not debuggged?

Comment: A naive solution: `next(n for n in s if s.count(n)==1) #  --> 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the [i] at line 7.
This is what propably what throws the error.
You could also make this faster with numpy.

```py
mydict = {num: count for num, count in zip(np.unique(s))}
```

This is exactly what you want to do.
Then to find the first unique number you can do:

```py
for num in s:
    if mydict[num] == 1:
        break
```

num is afterwards the first occuring unique number.

Comment: Thank you.this was solved by correcting this line(You missed the [i] at line 7. This is what propably what throws the error)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer for your problem by looking for counting occurrences in lists.

Anyway, here are a couple ways for you to get it:

## 1 (using a For Loop)

```
# Stops at the first unique number
s = [1,2,1,2,3,5]
for n in s:
    r = s.count(n)
    if r == 1:
        print(f'{n} is unique')
        break
```

## 2 (using Comprehension List)

```
# Without stopping at the first unique
s = [1,2,1,2,3,5]
[ print(f'{n} is unique') for n in s if s.count(n) == 1 ]
```

## 3 (using Comprehension List)

```
# Stopping at the first unique number and exit the program
import sys
s = [1,2,1,2,3,5]
[ [ print(f'{n} is unique'), sys.exit() ] for n in s if s.count(n) == 1 ]
```

## 4 (the most elegant way)

```
# This doesn't stop the loop and doesn't exit the program
print(f'{[ n for n in s if s.count(n) == 1 ][0]} is unique')
```